# How to access store values to components in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

This is my store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
        isLog : !!localStorage.getItem('situation')
    },
    mutations: {
        loginUser (state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = true
            state.isLog = true
        },
        logoutUser (state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = false
            state.isLog = false
        },
    }
})
```

but when I call {{state.isLoggedIn}} in the display.vue, I am not getting the values.

In display.vue, I use

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import store from '../store';

export default {
  name: "BookList",
  data() {
    return {
      students: [],
      errors: [],
      state: this.state.isLoggedIn,

    };
  },
})
</script>

<template>
{{this.state}}
</template>
```

But I am getting errors when i done this way. Please can anyone please help what is the problem.

Comment: `this.$store.state.isLoggedIn`, see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components (scroll down a bit). Alternatively, check out the `mapState` helper ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: `store.state.isLoggedIn` in your case, because you directly import your store to component

Comment: @dziraf both (ie `this.$store` and `store`) should refer to the same object due to `Vue.use(Vuex)` and assuming OP has injected the store into their `Vue` instance

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to import your store into your component. Instead, you should access it using `this.$store`.

For accessing the store state, the better (and recommended) way is to [map the state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) within your component.

In your example it should be something like:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    ...
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            isLoggedIn: 'isLoggedIn'
        })
     }
}
```

In your template, `this` is not needed. Just call the property by its name:

```
{{ isLoggedIn }}
```

Comment: @Jared No, you need to [commit](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) it to the store. You can do with `$store.commit('your-mutation', payload)` or dispatching an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) that mutates the state.